# gstreamer: how to shift the time of rendering of one stream taken from file

Tags: time, rendering, gstreamer, offset

I have two media files (say, "file0" and "file1") and 
I want to merge them into a single one with "picture-in-picture" effect - 
the content from "file0" to be displayed on the whole window, 
and the content from "file1" will be shown on the top-left corner in 
the smaller box.

One more point is that the content from "file1" should be rendered 
some time later from the base time, at the point marked as "X1" on 
the diagram below.

[image]

In other words, if I take "videotestsrc" as a video source input, 
I would get the following sample pipeline which illustrates what I need
to get as a result of this task:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev \
 videotestsrc pattern="snow" num_buffers=100 ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=15/1" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_0 \
 videotestsrc pattern=5 timestamp-offset=3000000000 num_buffers=30 ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=120,height=80,framerate=15/1" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_1  \
 videomixer name="videomixer" ! autovideosink
```

(you'll see snowy 320x240 window with small green box appearing 
after three seconds from the start for two seconds)

So, the question is - what is the best way to shift the time of rendering 
the content from file1 ? (either by the means of gstreamer plugins, specifying a parameter in a pipeline, OR by doing an API call)

Comment: Hmm, if you're willing to create a wrapper program, you could add the second stream after five seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally the answer: it is possible by calling [gst-pad-set-offset](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#gst-pad-set-offset) for particular sink pads of videomixer and audiomixer elements. So, in the example above, you would get sink_1 pads of video- and audio-mixers and specify the offset by calling 'gst-pad-set-offset'. Works like a charm.

Special thanks to Sebastian Dröge who answered very [similar question](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gst-launcher-1-0-setting-pad-offset-tp4672162p4672168.html)